# Retrieve Mutiple records in hql even some tables have no record

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have one situation, Need to retreive records from multiple tables and there is possibility that some tables has no record as per the condition criteria
 For example:-

```
select *
from A a, B b, C c, D d, E e 
where a.CERT_REQUEST_ID = '' 
  and a.CERT_OBJ_RLT_CD = '' 
  and b.CERT_ID = a.CERT_OBJ_KEY_ID 
  and b.CERT_TRS_SEQ_NBR = a.CERT_TRS_SEQ_NBR 
  and b.CERT_TRS_SEQ_NBR = c.CERT_TRS_SEQ_NBR 
  and b.CERT_ID = c.CERT_ID 
  and c.CERT_OBJ_KEY_ID = d.CERT_OVERRIDE_ID 
  and e.CERT_WORDING_ID = c.CERT_OBJ_KEY_ID
```

There is possibility that tables E,D have no records for the mentioned criteria. So in this case also i need records of other tables.

I can achieve this by Left outer join but HQL not support the joins and also these tables not mapped.
So, how to achieve this in hql. Please please help

Answer (score 0):

HQL does support joins (including left joins): [link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins).

However, you won't be able to use HQL if the tables are not mapped.

You could use a query in SQL with [createSQLQuery()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#createSQLQuery%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I executed as sql query, i got the data also but i the result not in objects. How i can come to know that which details belong to which table. With hibernate , I can in below way but not with SQL:-                                                   if (listCert != null && listCert.size() > 0) {
   for (Object[] objArray : listCert) {

    B cert = (B) objArray[1];}}

Comment: @shahzar [See this to know how to get entities from SQL queries.](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#d0e13696) I can't be more explicit without knowing your entities and what do you want to do.

Comment: When i execute a hql query then i'll get the record in object form and for example:-listCert is the result having record of 5 tables the i can retrive different objects in a way:-                      List<Object[]> listCert = dao.executeNamedQuery(strBuffer.toString(),
    params, values);                                     if (listCert != null && listCert.size() > 0) {
   for (Object[] objArray : listCert) {
    B cert = (B) objArray[1];
    C certObj = (C) objArray[3];
    D certOverride = (D) objArray[4];
    E certWording = (E) objArray[5];}}